# html get request does not deliver tags that contain umlaute / non ascii characters

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib2

I'm doing a get request in python

```
r = requests.get('http://www.lidl.de/de/billiger')
html_file = r.text
```

This site shows the current products that are cheaper now.
Like you can see on the webpage product 5 and 6 have the german umlaut ("ä")

If you have a look at the variable html_file you will see these two entries completely missing. 
If I download that file with firefox and process that file directly I have the entries in it.

So `requests` and so is `urllib2` is somehow removing these entries. Encoding is UTF-8 which is the same like the get-request firefox is issueing when i browse to that site.

Anyone knows how to fix that?

Regards

Comment: Can you post `r.text` on [Gist](http://gist.github.com)? I see a HTML page when I open the link with Firefox

Comment: I can see "ä" in variable - maybe everything is OK but you `print()` on console without `utf-8` and it can't display this letter.